# Is a nearby parallel universe still in use as an explanation for dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter

Is the [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekpyrotic_universe) which explains dark matter as the effect of a nearby parallel universe still used as an explanation for dark matter, or does this theory already lie on the pile of forgotten theories?

Comment: I think we can easily send that back to the scifi novel that it came from.

Comment: I think he is referring to a theory related to branes, I'm sure I have heard of it before...

Comment: The theory is well and alive: http://www.physics-astronomy.com/2015/03/is-gravity-from-parallel-universe.html#.V0TLJvkrJD8

Comment: @CuriousOne Then why says bruce smitherson that the theory is well and alive?

Comment: You have to ask him that, I never use the word "theory" for what is pure and unwarranted speculation.

Comment: What physics would become without speculation? I am not sure but nothing good.

Comment: @brucesmitherson: Wikipedia has a fairly good list of science fiction novels with parallel universes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fiction_employing_parallel_universes. It shouldn't be too hard to understand the distinction between these (often highly entertaining) ideas and solid science. :-)

Comment: what does it has to do with the work of serious people? that research is done by established researchers that are, likely, knowledgeable in their subject. It might sound pretentious to disregard them as crackpots.

Comment: @brucesmitherson: Physicists are tasked with explaining the properties of _this_ universe, they aren't being asked to invent a new one when they can't. There is nothing special about dark matter in this respect. When we discovered the neutrino, it was an indirect measurement and it turned out to be very hard to actually find these guys in the flesh. Nobody back then invented parallel universes to explain why they couldn't do it, initially. Same for the Higgs. We knew how hard it was to detect and we built the right machine, we didn't seek cheap excuses why it didn't show at LEP and Fermilab.

Comment: It´s a very interesting theory. Google `Dark matter and parallel universes` and see what comes out!

Comment: This is about whether some speculative ideas that involve something in physics are proper topics in this site. I would contend the comments about whether it is or not should be more fully and openly discussed in the meta site. My thought on this: 1)If the topic is being discussed in some serious physics circles, 2)is being discussed with plausible arguments and using logic, and 3) has some arguments as to why or how it does not violate known physics, it should be acceptable as a topic here. If university researchers can discussit, why not here. Answer the question or go to a chat room

Comment: Another point, more to the subject itself. The reference by smitherson does not actually discuss dark matter, but instead dark energy. Maybe I missed it. And I did not see any good scientific or serious discussion in that reference. Out of respect of the people in this site there should be more serious references and/or description of the topic by the questioner. The multiverse (which I have also serious problems with) has been treated from String Theory to some extent, in universes in different branes. If I knew enough about the theory I'd offer some answer, but I don't.

Comment: I think the OP is probably referring to something along the lines of Ekpyrotic theory, which, while it's not the current standard in cosmology, is a serious theory grounded in physics. It has nothing to do with dark matter, though, but rather dark energy; I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of theory is still an active research topic as can be seen by running [this search](https://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+ekpyrotic/0/1/0/all/0/1), which turns up plenty of recent papers related to the topic, including several in credible refereed journals. It is not widely regarded as complete/correct/accepted, but it is grounded in sensible physics... though to me some parts of it are a bit strange.

Comment: I mean the following mechanism. Suppose (to make it understandable for our minds) the universe is one-dimensional. This line is placed on a cylinder, and another line (literally) lies on the other side of the cylinder. Only gravity can leave the lines, so it can reach the other line. This means matter on both lines experiences more gravity than without the other line, and that the Planck distance gets smaller (for this, the people at CERN expect to find micro black holes). Witten made his contribution. I think this scenario is ruled out by an accidental celestial event. Hence my question.

Comment: @descheleschilder You should probably edit in some detail to your question, then?

Comment: You´re absolutely right! But to disprove the theory I first had to know if it was still going around in the world of astronomy, and it´s indeed the Ekpyrotic theory of two nearby branes. Or, in my toy example, lines: infinitely long, one-dimensional branes (not to be confused with the tiny one-dimensional strings; the lines are an aid to visualize ), just like the two-dimensional branes extending to infinity but it´s not clear to me if these branes have something analog to the cylinder in my toy-example where the can move on. The Planck length gets bigger, contrary to what I wrote.